# edit exercise component not being displayed

Tags: reactjs

exercise list component

```
    const Exercise = props => (
    <tr>
      <td>{props.exercise.username}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.description}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.duration}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.date.substring(0,10)}</td>
      <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/"+props.exercise._id}>edit</Link> | <a href="/#" onClick={() => { props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id) }}>delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>


  )
```

app.js

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="container">
    <Navbar />
    <Route path="/" exact component={ExerciseList} />
    <Route path="/edit/id" component={EditExercise} />
    <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
    <Route path="/user"  component={CreateUser} />
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: browser view]

in the browser edit exercise component is not seen although i have given the correct path

Comment: perhaps try: `path="/edit/:id"`

Comment: And remember to use `switch` outside the `route`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For route which has dynamic value involved, you will need to add a colon to that parameter. So your route will look like this:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
```

Check this for reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Hope this helps!